# use the same modal in multiple html page without repeat it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have confirm modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="confirm-modal-title">Confirmation Message</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <strong><p id="confirm_model_body"></p></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm_model_yes_button" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want to use the same code in another html page without repeat it how can i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Create an php file with this content and include the file everywhere you need it with php. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) is a great example on how

Comment: Please include more details about the answer than just linking to an offsite source.  That link could go dead and then this answer has minimal information.

Comment: i don't wont to use php

Answer (score 0):

This may be too open ended and lacks some information,, but I'll give it a shot assuming this is using bootstrap or something similar, I think I can help. First, you can put the modal, into memory in your javascript, by assigning it to a variable.

```
const modalContainer = document.createElement('div');

modalContainer.innerHTML = '<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_modal" role="dialog">' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">' +
       ...
       ...
 '</div>';

// you may need to do something to hide it by default

 document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', modalContainer);
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

The documentation includes ways to trigger it that are built into Bootstrap.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="example

ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```